# How to import a package from a linked folder resource in a Flash Builder project?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have this folder structure:
`/source/MapEditor` where the main project resides. (with its `src` folder inside)
`/source/Geonerd` with some classes declared as belonging to the `Geonerd` package.

I've tried to include the `Geonerd` package, with no luck.
How do I import it? ( the yellow warning icon says *Definition Geonerd.Polygon could not be found* )

If I copy the `Geonerd` folder instead, inside the `src` folder, I can do `import Geonerd.*` correctly, but not with the linked folder.

Note: it's not a .swc library, it's just the .as sources inside a folder all within the `Geonerd` package.

[image]

Note 2: I added the folder to the project's *ActionScript Build Source Path* but doesn't work either:
Note that what should be the *Geonerd* Package is recognized as *(default package)*

[image]

Update: if I make the linked sources belong to the anonymous package, I can import them, but the problem is they *have* to be in their own package to avoid name clash with other libraries I'm using. And that libraries in turn are also in their own package and I need to import them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had to add a folder that had a folder inside, named `Geonerd` so then Flash Builder recognizes it as the Package *Geonerd* and not just a default package.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it as an external folder.
Select Project -> Properties -> ActionScript Build Path. On the build path properties page, select the Source Path tab. Click the Add Folder button. Enter or browse to the folder, click OK. The folder is added to the source path.

Should look similar to: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/files/2012/05/snapshot1.png

Comment: Ok, but the image you posted shows the Library path tab, not the Source path tab.  
I don't know how you got that NELibrary in there, but mine are not a .SWC, it's just some source files in a folder, all inside the Geonerd package.
I tried adding the path to the source path but it doesn't work either, and it doesn't even recognize the sources package Geonerd, it just shows them as belonging to the default package of that source path.

Comment: You could see I wrote 'select the Source Path tab'. It's all there :) The image is 'similar' to what you should see.
Glad you made it.

Comment: I know, I figured that out, you can tell by the phrase "I tried adding the path to the source path but it doesn't work either" but it was a different thing what I was doing wrong. Thanks for helping though.